# Color chooser control for VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, colors, userform

I have some ActiveX Buttons (CommandButton1 and CommandButton2) on, lets say Sheet1. I would like to be able to choose and change their backcolour from a userform. Changing the colour is not the problem, the thing is been able to pick the coulour. Is there any control for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [this site](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/site/tip/creating_a_color_picker_dialog_box/)? Or perhaps [this thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/547126-excel-colors-dialog-visual-basic-applications.html)?

Comment: Yeap, been there. The first site example doesn't work. And about the thread... I dont really understand how to use the Application.Dialogs(xlDialogColorPalette).Show command...